# Is it possible to take someone to small claims court while living and working abroad?

Tags: small-claims-court, wills

My father passed away two years ago. My brother was issued executor of my father's assets. My father left a will stating I have equal rights to the assets he left when he passed away.

I live and work abroad. Will I be able to take my brother to small claims court for not issuing my share of my father's estate?

Comment: Sorry for your loss. It will depend on the laws of the country that has jurisdiction.  What country did your father live in?  (If the US, what state?)

Comment: I'm working overseas, but I'm from California and my father passed away in California. We are both US citizens. Al of my fathers assets are in California. I appreciate all replies.